# logic help for smallest/largest value

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I went thru so many version of the algorithm to sort smallest and largest that my brain is fried. The book up to this point and searching online haven't helped at all. 
I'm having difficulties at saving the last.
I used 3 in, 10 cm and 5 cm as test cases. Entering 3 in first, becomes the largest, entering 5 cm second becomes smallest and then 10 cm becomes smallest again. Tried different version for over 2 hours, even re-wrote that entire section. In the book Programming Principles and Practices using C++, its in the review section, before that I cant find anything to help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double>all_meters;

    double smallest= 0,print_smallest, largest = 0,print_largest, num = 0;
    string unit, s_input, num_s_input, small_unit, large_unit;

    while(cin.good()){

        cout << "\n\t\t\t\tEnter '|' to exit.\n\n";
        cout << "\t\tNumber to compare followed by white space and unit:";
        cin >> num_s_input;

        if(num_s_input.compare("|") == 0 || (s_input.compare("|") == 0)){
            double sum = 0;
            for (double x : all_meters) sum+=x;
            cout << "Sum: " << setprecision(4) << sum <<  "m\n";
            cout << "Smallest number: " << print_smallest << small_unit << endl
                 << "Largest number: " << print_largest << large_unit << endl
                 << "Total number of values: " << all_meters.size() << endl
                 << "All the entered numbers converted to meters are: \n";
            for (double i = 0; i<all_meters.size(); ++i){
                cout << all_meters[i] << setprecision(2) <<"m ";
            }
            cout << "\nAlright now, goodbye then !\n" << endl;
            break;
            }
        else{
            cin >> s_input;
            num = strtod(num_s_input.c_str(), NULL);
            unit = s_input;

            double meter = 0;
            if(unit=="cm"){
                    meter = num / 100;}

            else if(unit=="in"){
                    meter = num / 39.370;}

            else if(unit=="ft"){
                    meter = num / 3.2808;}

            else if(unit=="m"){
                    meter = num;}

            else {
                cout << "\n\tYou entered wrong unit!\t\n";}

            if(largest==0){
                largest = meter;
                print_largest = num;
                large_unit = unit;
                cout << num << unit << " largest so far.\n";
            }
            else if(smallest==0&&meter<largest){
                smallest = meter;
                print_smallest = num;
                small_unit = unit;
                cout << num << unit << " smallest so far.\n";
            }
            else if(largest<meter){
                largest = meter;
                print_largest = num;
                large_unit = unit;
                cout << num << unit << " largest so far.\n";
            }
            else if(smallest>meter){
                smallest = meter;
                print_smallest = num;
                small_unit = unit;
                cout << num << unit << " smallest so far.\n";
            }
            all_meters.push_back(meter);
            sort(all_meters.begin(),all_meters.end());
        }
    }
}
```

Managed to solve it without using limit, added the new changes to the code. Thanks for the help guys !

Comment: You need to actually ask a question, you can't just say "Here is my problem, please solve it."

Comment: my bad, I added comments where I'm having trouble understanding. You dont need to solve it. Just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose a standard unit of measure. The question suggests meters, so use that (you can use `float` or `double` for this, depending on what precision you need).

The problem is then simple, create some variables for the sum, smallest seen, and largest seen, the for each new input, convert to the standard format, and update the variables.

The solution (to get you started, not working code) might look something like this:

```
// You can represent the different types of units as integers
float convertToMeters(float unconvertedValue, int unit) {
  // Convert unconvertedValue based on unit
}

float smallest = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
float largest  = std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest();
float sum      = 0.0f;

// Update for each new input
while (new_input) {
  float convertedValue = convertToMeters(new_value, unit);

  // Update total
  sum += convertedValue;

  // Update smallest and largest
  if (convertedValue > largest) largest = convertedValue;
  else if (convertedValue < smallest) smallest = convertedValue;
}
```

As Nathan mentioned, `#include <limits>` for the limits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already most of the code and requirements. What I'm working on is to overwrite smallest with the condition that its smaller than largest and next time around the loop to overwrite it based on the condition that its smaller than previous smallest. Is there any way to do that with logical operators ?

Comment: I've showed you how to do it, check the last line of my answer. You don't need to check that the new value is smaller than both the largest and the smallest. If smallest < largest (which it should be) then you only need to check that new_value < smallest on each iteration. Similarly, you just need to check if new_value > largest to update largest. If you initialise smallest and largest correctly, as both Nathan and I showed, then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I understand, ill do it this way. Wanted to solve it without using <limits>, since I havent come across it in the book yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your problem comes from the fact that you are initializing `smallest` to 0.  If you never enter anything smaller than 0 then `smallest` will never change.

When finding the minimum and maximum values you want to set the the initial value to the largest or smallest number respectively that it can hold.  So in this case we would use

```
double smallest = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); 
double largest = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()
double num = 0;
```

This was anything in your data set should be less than `smallest` and everything should be grater than `largest`.

This does require `#include <limits>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I was trying to attempt is to overwrite smallest with the condition that its smaller than largest and next time around the loop to overwrite it based on the condition that its smaller than previous smallest. Is there any way to do that with logical operators ? Been experimenting for a long while... nothing in the book issimilar to it.

Comment: @Rotsin There may be but I am not sure,  General it is just done with an if condition.

Comment: Figure it out !! It came to while taking a shower :D !