# Find the smallest value in a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I am pretty new when it comes to programming with STL and I thought I was getting the hang of it. But I am a little perplexed about this one bit. My goal is to take in 5 values, then print out my values, print the highest value among them, print the average, and print the lowest among them ( my problem ). It seems that my variable "low" is given the value of 0 and I do not know why this is. I have tested to see if my values are being read in and to my knowledge, they are. So if anyone could please enlighten me to why I cannot seem to get the proper lowest value, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

```
vector<double> vecList;
int x = 0;
double high = 0;
double low = 0;
double sum = 0;

cout << "Enter Integer Values, then press Ctrl(z) to Quit:" << endl;

for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
 cin >> x;
 sum = sum + x;
 vecList.push_back(x);
}
vector<double>::iterator intVecIter;

cout <<"List contains: ";
for (intVecIter = vecList.begin(); intVecIter != vecList.end(); ++intVecIter)
cout << *intVecIter << " ";
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    if(vecList[i] > high)
    {
            high = vecList[i];
    }
// prints out "0"
    if(low > vecList[i])
    {
            low = vecList[i];
    }
 }
cout << endl << "Largest: "<< fixed << setprecision(2) << high << endl;
cout << "Smallest: "<< fixed << setprecision(2) << low << endl;
cout << "Average: " << fixed << setprecision(2)<< (sum/5);
return 0;
```

Comment: Think about how you initialised `low`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [logic help for smallest/largest value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046549/logic-help-for-smallest-largest-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initalize low to a big value not 0, otherwise this

```
   if(low > vecList[i])
```

is never true

Comment: I feel like such a dummy! Thank you. I completely overlooked that.

Comment: Or just initialise with `low = vecList.front()`.

Comment: you should initialize both low and hight to vecList.front() if you allow negative numbers, otherwise you can always come up with input that will not give the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to learn STL, take a look at the [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and it has some helper functions which will give the min, max and sum (accumulate is the actual function name) for a given range.

Comment: You actually want `min_element` and `max_element`

Comment: Or even [minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).